# how to focus the last added content at the end of UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

In my project i am having scrollview.when i drag a image it will add some content inside the scrollview.
Likewise i can add  many times by wish.when the content of scrollview increase it will update the content size.

But i want the scrollview to focus last added content in the scroll.
how to do that?please help me with some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be more clear, do you want to be able to scroll to the last added element? If so,

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```